# Change a specific TD's background color on click button with JavaScript/ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have `<tr id="tr_color" >`, I want to make it so that when I click on the Button "Active account" inside that `td`, the value "1" will add in column 'active_account' in database and this work with me. Also the `background-color` for `td` will change to blue and here the problem! not change with me.

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function active_user_account() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "check_data.php",
        data:'conf_data='+ document.getElementById( "active_account" ).value + '&id='+ document.getElementById( "id_this_user" ).value,
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data){
            document.getElementById("tr_color").style.backgroundColor = "blue !important";
        },
        error:function (){}
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: TR or TD? <tr id="tr_color" > in your code, but 'specific TD's background' in title?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have `!important` in styles added with JavaScript. Change it to

```
document.getElementById("tr_color").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

and it should work. Alternatively, if you really need to use `!important`, try doing it with a class instead:

```
document.getElementById("tr_color").className += " importantClass";
```

with the following CSS:

```
.importantClass { background-color: blue !important; }
```

Comment: The same problem , also when I add class like what you say not work ! and ever time  when I click in the button add a new class in tr :(

Comment: @BudoorAyhd could you make a fiddle showing the problem?